# SQL JOIN 3 Tables all query combinations

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

[image: VENN DIAGRAM]

Table_A (PK,VALUE)

- | 1 | FOX |
- | 2 | COP |
- | 3 | TAXI |
- | 4 | LINCOLN |
- | 5 | ARIZONA |
- | 6 | WASHINGTON |
- | 7 | DELL |
- | 10 | LUCENT |

Table_B (PK,VALUE)

- | 1 | TROT |
- | 2 | CAR |
- | 3 | CAB |
- | 6 | MONUMENT |
- | 7 | PC |
- | 8 | MICROSOFT |
- | 9 | APPLE |
- | 11 | SCOTCH |

Table_C (PK,VALUE)

- | 1 | UP |
- | 3 | RIGHT |
- | 7 | LEFT |
- | 10 | EAST |
- | 11 | WEST |
- | 14 | DOWN |
- | 20 | NORTH |
- | 21 | SOUTH |

What are the MySQL JOIN queries that need to be written to obtain each individual region in the VENN diagram shown:

So the output for each region should display the Key Value pairs that match in each table. Check 7 below to get an idea of what should be displayed after the query is run.

1 => 4,5

2 => 8,9

3 => 2,6

4 => 14,20,21

5 => 10

6 => 11

7 => 1,3,7 as {(1,FOX;1,TROT;1,UP),(3,TAXI;3,CAB;3,RIGHT),(7,DELL;7,PC;7,LEFT)}

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Mostly I am stuck trying to construct everything except for the full intersection for 7 my query is the following: SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_a A INNER JOIN table_b B on A.PK=B.PK INNER JOIN table_c C on A.PK=C.PK;

Comment: For instance, for area 1 what have you tried and where are you stuck? Why is it not working? These are very simple `join` and `except` queries...

Comment: Ok figured out 1 as well:SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_a A LEFT JOIN table_b B on B.PK=A.PK LEFT JOIN table_c C on C.PK=A.PK where B.PK is NULL and C.PK is NULL;

Comment: Don't understand why this question is being down voted however are we not supposed to ask questions we are having difficulty to solve on this site? The question is pretty straight forward, clear and useful to know so again why the down vote?

Comment: Subsequently the queries for 2 and 4 are as follows: SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_b B LEFT JOIN table_a A on B.PK=A.PK LEFT JOIN table_c C on C.PK=B.PK where C.PK is NULL and A.PK is NULL;  and  SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_c C LEFT JOIN table_a A on C.PK=A.PK LEFT JOIN table_b B on C.PK=B.PK where A.PK is NULL and B.PK is NULL;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/* 1 */

SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_a A LEFT JOIN table_b B on B.PK=A.PK LEFT JOIN table_c C on C.PK=A.PK where B.PK is NULL and C.PK is NULL;

/* 2 */

SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_b B LEFT JOIN table_a A on B.PK=A.PK LEFT JOIN table_c C on C.PK=B.PK where C.PK is NULL and A.PK is NULL;

/* 3 */

SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_a A INNER JOIN table_b B on A.PK=B.PK LEFT JOIN table_c C on A.PK=C.PK where A.PK=B.PK and C.PK is NULL;

/* 4 */

SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_c C LEFT JOIN table_a A on C.PK=A.PK LEFT JOIN table_b B on C.PK=B.PK where A.PK is NULL and B.PK is NULL;

/* 5 */

SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_a A LEFT JOIN table_b B on A.PK=B.PK INNER JOIN table_c C on A.PK=C.PK where A.PK=C.PK and B.PK is NULL;

/* 6 */

SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_b B LEFT JOIN table_a A on A.PK=B.PK INNER JOIN table_c C on B.PK=C.PK where B.PK=C.PK and A.PK is NULL;

/* 7 */

SELECT A.PK as A_PK, A.Value as A_Value, B.PK as B_PK, B.Value as B_Value, C.PK as C_PK, C.Value as C_Value from table_a A INNER JOIN table_b B on A.PK=B.PK INNER JOIN table_c C on A.PK=C.PK;

Now I wonder if this could be done with keeping the JOIN clause as INNER JOIN and not mixing LEFT or RIGHT JOINS but I don't want to get down voted again for posting a question.